# Showing that the integral of $x^nf(x)=0$ where $f$ is Lebesgue Integrable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying solve this but I'm not sure that is correct.

The exercise is:

> If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is lebesgue integrable, show that:
>   $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\int_0^1x^nf(x)=0 $$

**My attempt**:

Consider the sequence $\{|x^nf(x)|\}$ that are a sequence uniformly limited by $|f(x)|$ (this is it? I can affirm this?). Note that: $|x^nf(x)|\leq|f(x)|$. As $f(x)$ is lebesgue integrable so $|f(x)|$ is too. Now I apply the Dominated convergence theorem but I do not know if that's ... I can say that this sequence converges punctually?

Comment: What limit is supposd to be $0$? The expression does not depend on $n$. Also, your title speaks of an integral equalling $0$??

Comment: Sorry! I edited the post. @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got pretty much all the pieces already:

Since $f$ is integrable, it's finite almost everywhere. Hence if $0 \le x < 1$, and $f(x)$ is finite,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n f(x) = f(x) \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$$

Furthermore, $x^n \le 1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$, so that $|x^n f(x)| \le |f(x)|$ for a.e. $x$.
Thus the dominated convergence theorem applies and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n f(x) dx = \int_0^1 0 dx = 0$$

Comment: To apply the dominated convergence theorem you need $x^nf(x)$ measurable. Can you garanted that?

Comment: @Felipe $f$ is a pointwise limit of simple functions $f_n$, and each $x^2 f_n$ is measurable (prove this!).

Comment: Now I understand! $x^2f_n$ is measurable because is a composite with continuous and a measurable fucntion!!

Comment: [off topic] If you like measure questions, I have a question that has an open bounty worth +100 here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657788/a-question-about-jordan-measure-and-the-formalism-and-in-my-writing